# Android: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.graphics.Canvas.drawLine(Canvas.java:809) (probably related to my drawable resource)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, drawable

I am trying to build a child view with 7 columns and 24 TextViews in each column.

I get an exception when my activity starts and it does not have my package anywhere in the stack trace.

Here is my background drawable resource for each of the 24 text views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item><shape><solid android:color="#CCC"/></shape></item>
    <item android:top=".5pt" android:bottom=".5pt">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <size android:height="1pt" android:color="#CCC" android:dashWidth="1pt" android:dashGap="1pt" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

<strike>The CPU goes to 100% for a second or two before this happens.</strike>

I am using the emulator for Android 2.2

Here is my exception.

```
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawLine(Canvas.java:809)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.draw(GradientDrawable.java:347)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.draw(LayerDrawable.java:320)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6725)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6846)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6502)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.onAnimationStart(ViewGroup.java:1253)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1499)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-26 16:51:38.084: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(955):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

#### Edit

Renaming size to stroke eliminates the crash but I do not get a dotted line. I want a horizontal dotted line either in the middle or on the bottom of the drawable.

Comment: So does it work if you don't set any background for the text views?

Comment: Just a suggestion, can you try it with a shape defined for the first element? (i.e. `<shape android:shape="rectangle" .../>`

Comment: @kcoppock: Just did. It did not help.

Comment: Can you try it with pixel widths instead of fractional points? That's the first time I've seen someone use point sizes for one of these (not that it's an unusual idea, but just grasping at straws).

Comment: Tried dip values instead of pt values and it made no difference. Tried renaming size to stroke and at least it does no crash but I do not get a dotted line in the middle like I am looking for. @kcoppock

Comment: Change it to `<stroke android:width="1pt" ...>` instead of using android:height. Looking at the docs again, I think this should fix it, and get you the dotted line you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The crash occurs because GradientDrawable.mStrokePaint is null, which is in turn because you did not specify a `<stroke>` in your XML.

Changing `<size>` to `<stroke>` will fix it, but you also need to change the stroke colour to be different to the background colour, i.e:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item><shape><solid android:color="#CCC"/></shape></item>
    <item android:top=".5pt" android:bottom=".5pt">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:height="1pt" android:color="#FF000000" android:dashWidth="1pt" android:dashGap="1pt" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Duh! I could have thought of that!. I added a layer in the middle which was white. My intention was that the first layer (item) would be the top and bottom border. That is why I had the offset. Thank you for your answer.